# Что лучше: много юзеров mySQL или один?

Tags: mysql

Есть много однотипных сайтов на CMS Drupal.
У всех есть базы mySQL.
Пока сайтов было мало, я не задумывался и подключал их к БД одним и тем же юзером.

Но сейчас время от времени появляется ошибочка: "User ... already has more than 'max_user_connections' active connections in lock_may_be_available()..."

Как поступить грамотнее? Раздать каждому сайту по юзеру mySQL или увеличить количество одновременных подключений одному?
Сайтов — около сотни, все работают.

Comment: Как минимум, разделение юзеров с грамотной выдачей доступа увеличит безопасность, потому что взлом одного сайта не позволит прочитать базы других сайтов

Comment: Вообще-то каждый сайт должен иметь свои собственные учётные данные для доступа. И, возможно, не одну учётку, а несколько, для разных операций и с разными правами.